# Copy-Item and Join-Path creates a folder instead of a file

Tags: powershell

I have an issue where combining Copy-Item and using Join-Path in the destination leads to folder creation with file & extension name in folder name instead of copying the original file.

I have tried several variations of the following code. Also I have tried using {} for Destination to make it a script block but that ended up throwing an error saying that there was no input and therefore it could not be evaluated. I have also tried setting -ItemType to file, but that throws the same exception error. My PS version is v2.0.1.1 if that helps.

Assume all variables are instantiated and work properly, I have tested each one individually

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $Src -Recurse -Force | Where-Object {$_.Name -notcontains "Archive"}| 
ForEach-Object {
    if(!$_.PSIsContainer){
    $DateStr = $_.BaseName.Substring(0,2)+'/'+$_.BaseName.Substring(3,2)+'/'+$_.BaseName.Substring(6,4)  
    $FileDate = get-date $DateStr
    If ( $FileDate -ge $Date ) {
        $ParentOjbect = $_.Directory 
        $Parent = $ParentOjbect.Name
        Copy-Item -Path (Join-Path -Path $Src -ChildPath '\*' ) -Destination (Join-Path $Dst '{0} {1}' -f $Parent,$_.Name) 

    }}
}
```

Comment: `$_.Name -notcontains "Archive"` - that's not what `-contains` is for, it's for whether an item appears in a collection. Use `-notmatch` instead to check text in a string. (e.g. `'abc' -contains 'b'` is False).

Comment: Thanks for that catch. That fixed another problem but I don't think it has affected my current issue haha

Comment: I can't follow the logic for sure, but your script says "look for all files in all subdirectories, exclude 'archives', exclude old files, then ... over and over and over again copy everything including all those subdirectories, archives, and wrong dated files", because you `Copy-Item -Path $src\*` for every file. The Copy-Item behaviour seems to change depending on what is in the source Path selection, or what the first item is, or something. But there's not much point fixing that name issue directly, because the repeated copying the same things can't be correct.

Comment: (You can only use `{}` as a parameter for -Destination if you are pipelining into Copy-Item, and then use `$_` as the current loop item, e.g.  `gci * | copy-item -destination { $_.Name + "out" }`)

Comment: Thank you so much. The script should be to copy everything including all the files in those subdirectories, excluding archives, and wrong dated files. What should i have for the childpath instead to only indicate that particular object? $_.Name?

Comment: It's now doing exactly what I want it to do in the What If but nothing shows up in the folder when I check. Here is the What if: Performing operation "Copy File" on Target "Item: C:\Users\Bart Zhang\Downloads\Test Folder\450\450-PSV-9\Archive\03
-11-2016 Test Report.txt Destination: C:\Users\Bart Zhang\Desktop\New folder\Archive 03-11-2016 Test Report.txt".